# how to pass html form (in ejs) to javascript function in another ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have following html form in ejs file.
How do I pass password and confirmPassword input to checkPassword(javascript function) in another ejs?
the ejs include is done fine.

```
<% include ./registeruserutil %>
<form action="/user/register" method="POST" onSubmit="return <% checkPassword(this) %>">  <-- This is not form! -->    
                <div class="input-group mr-2 mb-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fas fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>        
                </div>

                <div class="input-group mr-2 mb-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fas fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </div>
```

function in other ejs file

```
<%
checkPassword = function(form) 
{
    console.log(form);
    return true;
}
%>
```

I actually followed this example.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/password-matching-using-javascript/

Comment: what is the other ejs file? Give some extra info if you want help.

Comment: there is one function in other ejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use ejs for this? Ejs is server-side javascript and we use it for server-side rendered values. You may as well use the javascript code in the same file like this.

```
<form onSubmit="return checkPassword(this) ">  
    <div class="input-group mr-2 mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-key fa-fw"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>        
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mr-2 mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-key fa-fw"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
    <input type = submit value = "Submit">
</form>
<script> 
  function checkPassword(form) {
    console.log(form.password.value);
    console.log(form.confirmPassword.value);
    //return true;
  }   
</script>
```